# Play 1.3. HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-1.x

I have model with field **files** in the **Request** class:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "file2request",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "request"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file"))
public List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mapping in the **File** class:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "files", targetEntity = Request.class)
public List<Request> requests;
```

It works perfectly on play version **1.2.5.3** or earlier. But on version **1.3.0** there is an error while I saving Request:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same
>   collection: models.base.requests.base.Request.files
>   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277)    at
>   models.base.requests.base.Request.setGeneratedUid(Request.java:543)
>     at models.base.requests.base.Request.lockedSetUid(Request.java:513)
>     at models.base.requests.base.Request.updateUid(Request.java:569)    at
>   models.base.requests.kindergarten.KindergartenRequest.saveCore(KindergartenRequest.java:416)
>     at
>   models.base.requests.kindergarten.KindergartenRequest.saveRequestsCore(KindergartenRequest.java:300)
>     at
>   controllers.requests.types.Kindergarten.create(Kindergarten.java:217)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:524)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:475)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:451)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:446)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:160)    at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same
>   collection: models.base.requests.base.Request.files   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:59)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:251)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:100)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1130)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1747)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:232)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)    ...
>   12 more

Comment: One of the bigger changes between Play 1.2.x and 1.3.0 is that a lot of libraries have been updated. The Hibernate version that is used went from 3.6.10 to 4.2.15. The answer to your problem is probably somewhere in that big leap. I'd look at the release- and migration notes of Hibernate to look for clues.